# Replace the first frame of a video with another frame using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB for a video processing task.

When I tried to create an object for the grayscale video (the video has a .FLV extension) using the **mmreader** function of MATLAB, it showed an warning saying that it cannot determine the number of frames.

Then when I tried to read the video using **read(mmreader)**, it showed an error saying not enough memory for 3246 frames.

Therefore I just read the first frame of the video, edited it and now trying to place the frame in the position of the first frame of the video.

**Things that I have done:**

1. Read and extracted the first frame of a grayscale video (the file has a .FLV extension) using **mmreader** function of MATLAB.
2. I embedded some text in the frame.

**Things that I want to do and need your help:**

1. Replace the first frame of the source video with the edited frame (i.e. the frame with the embedded text in it)
2. Save and Play the video.